# Got " Failed to get producer codec" error when use imsdroid lib to create video call

Tags: android, voip

Recently I am writing an android sip client using imsdroid library. 
The voice call is OK, but when I want to make an video call, I got 
 **E/org.doubango.ngn.sip.NgnAVSession(19728): Failed to get producer codec**

I have checked my code with imsdroid. but nothing wrong found. Can anyone help me to check this error? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two reasons for this to happen. First the sip packet (with sdp) received will not have the codec for the app to process.  Second, the codec is received but the app is not handling it properly.